# Scope en Laravel 5.5 no muestra resultados en la vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quiero mostrar los resultados de una búsqueda en una vista pero no muestra nada.
 ya realice el scope:

**Modelo Producto**

```
 public function scopeBuscar($query, $nombre){
        return $query -> where('nombre','LIKE', '%'.$nombre.'%');
    }
```

**Controlador**

Aquí si obtiene el texto que ingreso y realiza el filtrado pero no muestra nada en mi vista y no marca algún error

```
 public function index(Request $request){

            $productos = Producto::buscar($request->get('nombre'));
            return view('productos-buscar',compact('productos'));
 }
```

**Vista**

```
          @foreach($productos as $producto) 
          <div  style="background-image: url({{ asset('archivos/'.$producto->imagen) }})"></div>
           <h1>{{$producto->nombre}}</h1>
           <h2>Categoría: {{$producto->categorias['nombre']}}</h2>
           <p> {{$producto->descripcion}}</p>
           @endforeach
```

Comment: A esta línea `$productos = Producto::buscar($request->get('nombre'))` le hace falta un `get()` al final me parece, para poder obtener los resultados de tu consulta

Comment: Era eso, gracias!

Comment: Un gusto ayudar

Comment: Un gusto ayudar